# Mat-option cannot be converted to number

Tags: angular, validation, type-conversion, mat-option

I want to display a set of numbers in a menu and I use mat-select/mat-option.
I have a validator that checks if the values of the menu are numbers (since the user can either select a number from the menu or insert one from the keyboard).

I try to convert these values to numbers, before displaying them on the template as follows:

```
 nodes.forEach((node) => {
      console.log(typeof(node.x)); //string
      console.log(node.x); //10.0

      node.x = parseInt(node.x);
      console.log(typeof(node.x), node.x); //undefined, undefined

      this.options.push(node);
});
```

Why the values cannot be converted from strings to integers?
Also, why if I display them to the template without trying to convert them to numbers, the validator returns an error that the option is not a number?

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let node of options">
      {{ node["x"]}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Any reason you using `node.x` instead of `value.x` in the forEach loop?

Comment: @wei sorry, an error from the cp-paste I did. I correct it

Comment: try add `[value]="node.x"`: `<mat-option *ngFor="let node of options" [value]="node.x">`

Comment: you can also try (see the `+` to convert to number) `<mat-option *ngFor="let node of options" [value]="+node.x">`. BTW you wrote parseInt([node.x]); it's not parseInt(node.x) -without the `[``]`?